# how to refresh the combo box in c#? this the codes

Tags: c#

```
            string query = "SELECT * FROM inv.product;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string sprodID = myReader.GetString("productID");
                    cmbdel.Items.Add(sprodID);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _refresh_ exactly? You mean like `Clear()` or something? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: i have a table that values are connected to the list box, when i delete some values it is still shown on the combobox

Comment: sorry for the english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function of you existing code like this,

```
private void BindCombo()
{
            cmbdel.Items.Clear(); // Clear the combobox items here
            // And bind again...
            string query = "SELECT * FROM inv.product;";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string sprodID = myReader.GetString("productID");
                    cmbdel.Items.Add(sprodID);
                }
            }
}
```

Now you can call this method everytime when you delete the item.
Hope it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the following to remove an item from the combo box.

cmbdel.Items.RemoveAt(index);

cmbdel.Items.Remove(Value);

Before assigning new set of values,make sure that you call cmbdel.Items.Clear(). It will clear all the items from the combo box.